# Can these verbose CSS selectors be improved with SASS?

Tags: css, sass

Using Gravity Forms in WordPress you don't have much control over the field names it generates. So if you want to target fields 131, 132 and 133 in forms 11 and 15 here's what the CSS looks like (this is for some CSS to do something with the last li element in a list):

```
ul#input_11_131 li:last-child input,
ul#input_11_132 li:last-child input,
ul#input_15_131 li:last-child input,
ul#input_15_132 li:last-child input {
    //do something;
}

ul#input_11_133 li:last-child label,
ul#input_15_133 li:last-child label {
    //do a different thing;
}
```

This is a somewhat simplified version, we've actually dozens more lines like this.

Currently we're only using SASS for some simple things like nesting and variables.

But I'm wondering if SASS can help with this. Ideally, at the very least, we'd define the form numbers 11 and 15 at the start and maybe even the fields and loop through them.

Comment: @danjonescidtrix Things that are Off-Topic for Code Review: Pseudo-Code, Example Code, Stub Code, Example Code.

Answer (score -1):

You can also apply `css` using `HTML Attributes`.

**LIKE**

```
ul[id^='input_11_'] li:last-child input{    
  // Code common properties Here which is common in all input_11_* with li:last-child input
}
```

For Details check the w3school reference **[CSS SELECTORS](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)**

Comment: that is interesting, but i'm not sure it helps us as we don't want to target all input_11_*. which is why i am guessing only sass can deliver for us. but i must bear in mind your suggestion for other projects

Comment: If you don't want it to apply it on 1 or 2 selectors out of many then there is `:not()` selector as well in css. or you just simply override the css below that piece of code.